# How to check if a new Android phone/tablet has got no factory reset yet?

Tags: factory-reset, battery-life, data-monitoring

I would like to buy a factory-new tablet (Galaxy Tab S6) so I would like to check if the device has ever turned on (since the production date) and also how to make sure no factory reset has done yet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138097/discussion-on-question-by-david-how-to-check-if-a-new-android-phone-tablet-has-g).

Answer (score -3):

You can use ##786#. You can check RTN status of mobile. But you need to access hidden menu then you can use this code.

You can find uptime of mobile Go to setting / about phone / uptime. Compare it with date of purchase.

Comment: Uptime is Uptime since boot, not reset.

Comment: When reset uptime start from beginning and if you compare it with date of purchase. You can find mismatch.

Comment: @alecxs, It will not reveal date of firstboot/ factory reset. When you factory reset mobile, uptime will start from 0. Now you have factory reset 1 month ago and you purchase mobile 2 year ago. When you compare it will mismatch. And you find when was factory reset mobile.

Comment: You are rite. Every boot uptime change.